# Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(input)) Error

Tags: c#, pinvoke

`input600` is a float array of length 600.

```
IntPtr ip = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(input600));
```

The above statement throws the following error:

> Type 'System.Single[]' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure;
>   no meaningful size or offset can be computed.

What is the issue with this statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [`Marshal.SizeOf(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3ybkfb3.aspx):

> This method accepts an instance of a structure, which can be a
>   reference type or a boxed value type. The layout must be sequential or
>   explicit.

Arrays don't fulfill this requirement. However, you should be able to compute the space requirement like this, assuming that the array element type is either a primitive of a struct with the required layout:

```
IntPtr ip = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(input600.GetType().GetElementType())*input600.Length);
```

Comment: Throwing the following error - The type or namespace name 'input600' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?